# Shared fields mysql join issue

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables `orders`, `users`,`purchaseds`, and `cities` which `users`and `purchaseds` contain a field `city_id` as foreign key of `cities`, so I want to make a Join to get all tables content , the problem is `users` and `purchaseds` contain a different `city_id` values, which means i can't get `city_name`(field in `cities` table) for every table. How can I solve that ?

**Orders**

```
+--------+---------+x
| order_id| user_id |
+---------+---------+
| 2323    | 23      |
+---------+---------+
```

**Users**

```
  +--------+---------+x
  | user_id | city_id |
  +---------+---------+
  | 23      | 11      |
  +---------+---------+
```

**Purchaseds** 
**(Updated)**

```
   +--------+---------------+-----------+-----+
   | purchased_id   | order_id | user_id| city_id
   +----------------+---------+---------+-----+
   | 2222           |  230390  | 23     | 11
   +---------------+---------+----------+-----+
```

**Cities**

```
  +--------+-----------------+
  | city_id   | city_name    |
  +----------------+---------+
  | 11           |  New York |
  +---------------+---------+
```

Help please !!

Comment: given structure for purchases does not have any city_id ..

Comment: What do you mean "contain a different city_id values"? Can you show some sample data and desired results?

Comment: where is your query???

Comment: @Abhik Chakraborty, I updated the structure

Comment: @Marcus Adams, I mean, i should get city_name of users and purchaseds tables based on city_id of each one

Comment: u dont need to care about the city_id .. which city do u want to display if purchase city then join the purchase with city, else join with user which u need to do anyway by order id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multiple table aliases in your query to join the same table multiple times.

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders AS o
INNER JOIN Users AS u
    ON u.user_id = o.order_id
INNER JOIN Cities AS u_c
    ON u_c.city_id = u.city_id
INNER JOIN Purchaseds AS p
    ON p.order_id = o.order_id
INNER JOIN Cities AS p_c
    ON p_c.city_id = p.city_id
```